# Problem regarding installation of angular cli for node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, error-handling, installation, command-prompt

Can you please suggest what I should do next, I am stuck here for a while and nothing seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package.json is missing from the root directory of the project. Please check for package.json.